# Invalid literal for int() with base 10 : "some string", but the field in question is a foreign key to a charfield

Tags: python, django, database

I keep getting the invalid literal error for an int() with base 10.  The field in question is a foreign key to a class that only has one attribute and that attribute is a CharField, so I don't understand why I keep getting this error.  If I try to query the the Progress class it works fine, but when I search for a value for progress within the Tasks class I get the error.

I have already tried clearing my my migrations and re-migrating, it had no effect.

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Shell**

```
>>> from app.models import *
>>> a = Program.objects.filter(name="GM")
>>> print(a)
<QuerySet [<Program: GM>]>
>>> a = Tasks.objects.filter(program="GM")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GM'
```

I should be able to grab this object and manipulate it, I am certain that there is an object with program set to "GM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying in a wrong way.

It should be **`program__name="GM"`** instead of `program="GM"`.

```
a = Tasks.objects.filter(program__name="GM")
```

Saying `program="GM"` it tried to match string `"GM"` with integer `id` of program and hence gives error **`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GM'`**.

Comment: I love you, this is correct.  I vaguely had it in my head that the answer involved a double underscore.

Comment: @UsianBolt, glad that it helped. You can select the answer if it has resolved your query. Thanks.